# flutter auto route build runner error Route must have either a page or a redirect destination

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, router, flutter-routes

when i add a new route to router.dart and run the build runner i get the
Route must have either a page or a redirect destination
Error

below is my code in router.drat :

```
 
@MaterialAutoRouter(
  replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    AutoRoute(
      path: '/',
      page: SplashPage,
    ),
    AutoRoute(
      path: 'signInPage',
      name: 'SignInRouter',
      page: SignInPage,
    ),
    AutoRoute(
      path: 'noteOverviewPage',
      name: 'NoteOverviewRouter',
      page: NoteOverviewPage,
    ),
    AutoRoute(
      path: 'todoFormPage',
      name: 'todoFormRouter',
      page: TodoFormPage,
    ),
  ],
)
class $AppRouter {}
```

Answer (score 13):

There is also the possibility that you forgot to save the code of your new page (which happened to me). In that case your code might be there but the file is not yet saved so build runner will create this error.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this it, removing and re-import class patch

Answer (score 0):

in android studio when `build-runner` runs especially when runs in `watch` mode . you must save the files related to `build-runner` by `Ctrl+S` and wait to `build-runner` recompile files to save the changes. (you can see in `android studio` terminal).

so you should open these files and then press `Ctrl+S` on it:
`SplashPage` , `SignInPage` , `NoteOverviewPage` , `TodoFormPage` , `router.drat`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that all pages are stateless widgets, not statefull widgets! This weird move helped me. Met this strange problem today, maybe it's bug.

Comment: magically when I removed the key from 'todoFormPage' constructor idon't know why but it works : )

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I renamed one page, changed the uppercase letter to a small one (file name), and it ended up with a capital letter in the import and flutter didn't complain about it, so nothing worked. Just delete all the imports and do the imports again.